# Removing a row from a Gridview in Codebehind (getting exception?)

Tags: c#, asp.net, exception, data-binding, gridview

I'm trying to remove a row from my gridview manually, because for some reason, when I delete the item from the database and databind, the gridview still isn't updating. Here is the code I am using:

```
try
{
    gvCertifications.DeleteRow(int.Parse(commandArgs[1]));
}
catch (HttpException)
{
    //error
}
```

and for some reason, I'm always hitting that HttpException? I've tried placing this command both before *and* after my DataBind (because [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.deleterow.aspx) says that the HttpException occurs when the gridview isn't bound to a datasource)

The gridview is already bound to a datasource when it is loaded, so I don't know why I would be getting this exception...

Also, in case it helps, here is how I get `commandArgs[]`:

```
String[] commandArgs = e.CommandArgument.ToString().Split('|'); //before in same function as the try/catch block
```

and here are the commandargs from the .aspx file:

```
CommandArgument='<%#Eval("ThisId") + "|" + Container.DataItemIndex %>'
```

Comment: What is the CommandName that you mentioned? and on which event you wrote this code?

Comment: `CommandName = "delete"` and the event is `gvCertifications_RowCommand`

Comment: ok..then, did you wrote delete query on `deletecommand` property of the DataSource?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it doesn't necessarily answer my question, it solves the issue I was trying to hack around with it:

> from question:
>
> "...for some reason, when I delete the item from the database and databind, the gridview still isn't updating..."

Gridviews have predefined commands set up, such as 'select', 'edit', and 'delete'. When I try to define my own event to run with the command name 'delete', the program will try and run parts of my event alongside it's predefined event. This is what has been causing issues.

Answer (score 0):

If you used `sqldatasource` as a DataSource(as in [MSDN Example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.deleterow.aspx)) then, you need to write the delete query on `deletecommand` property of it. Or if you used `DataTabe` as a `DataSource`, then you need to handle `RowDeleting` event of the gridview. Check [this link](http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1497233&page=10) for sample.

Comment: I'm using custom commands, ie `GridView_RowCommand(...){ if(commandName == 'delete'){...}}`